# How do you create a text-buffer in QGIS' print composer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, printing, display

When creating a label you can create a buffer of another color around your text. Is there any way to do so in the print composer?

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about the labeling tool in print composer?

On macOS selecting a font offers You a lot of options, e.g. to add shadow to the text. But at least in QGis 3 I'm unable to use that.

A simple way would be to use HTML with the CSS text-shadow in the labeling tool:

```html
<p style="text-shadow:0px 0px 2px red;">Text with red glow around</p>
```